# Convert a varchar column to date for the month of December

Tags: varchar, to-date

I have a `varchar2` column in a table which saves dates in it with the format mask `'DD-MON-RR'`.

Now when I try to convert it with

```
{to_date(my_field,'DD-MON-RR')}
```

it returns accurate result except when I convert the December month, it throws an error

> literal does not match the format string

I have solved my problem by converting whole string to `{to_char}` again, but my question is: why does Oracle not let me convert the month of December saved in form of 'DEC'?

Comment: What is the day component?  Is it a number between 1 and 31?

Comment: Please tag with the product in question; dates are handled quite differently in different products!